# Scheduling an API call to save results to a database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, azure, api

I currently have a MERN stack web application hosted on Zeit, which is a simple stock simulator. I would like to schedule an API call to an endpoint every weekday at 4:00pm to pull some market data for the day, and save it to a MongoDB database. What is the best way to do this? For reference I am familiar with Microsoft Azure, and AWS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In AWS, you can use a CloudWatch events rule that triggers a lambda function every weekday at 4:00pm. 
Lambda function should have code to read the data and save data in MongoDB.

[How to schedule Cloudwatch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Functions with time trigger for it:

function.json

```
{
    "schedule": "0 0 4 * * *",
    "name": "myTimer",
    "type": "timerTrigger",
    "direction": "in"
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
module.exports = function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

    if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
    {
        context.log('Node is running late!');
    }
    context.log('Node timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);   
    //LOGIC TO PERFORM REQUEST / INSERT  on Mongo

    context.done();
};
```

more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=javascript